# Let $X$ be a topological space such that $A \subset X$ satisfies

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

> ${\bf EXERCISE:}$ Let $X$ be a topological space and $A \subset X$.
> Suppose that for each $x \in A$, there is some open set $U$ such that
> $x \in U \subset A$. Prove that $A$ is ${\bf open} $ in $X$.

#### Proof.

I think this is very easy but maybe I am interprenting the wrong way :

Since $\forall x \in A \exists U $ with$x\in U$ then $A = \bigcup_{x \in U} U $

since $U$ is open in $X$, then the union is also open in $X$ so $A$ is open in $X$. QED

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes it is. The condition guarantees that $A$ is a neighborhood of each of its points, hence "open". As you observe, it says that 
$A$ is a union of open sets, Since the $U$s being joined each depends on some $x$, probably best to write the last equality as $A = \bigcup_{x \in A} U_x$.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Also note that the converse holds (choosing $U = A$ for every $x$).

Comment: Yes, your proof is correct, apart from a typo in the union (which should be over $x\in A$). Just a comment on notation: emphasise that $U$ depends on $x$ by writing for instance $U_x$, so that $A=\bigcup_{x\in A} U_x$.